# What is the use of scanf() == 1?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf

My Code:

```
while(scanf("%f", &number) && number > 0) 
while(scanf("%f", &number) == 1 && number > 0)
```

What does this `== 1` and is this necessary?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean why there are 2 "==" ? Please edit your question.

Comment: [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of items successfully scanned.

Comment: The `== 1` is necessary because `scanf` can return `EOF` which will be implicitly considered `true`, but no value for `number` has been read.

Comment: Lesson, always explicitly test the return against the number of conversions you expect (this can be less than the total number in the format string if less than the total is expected)

Comment: @WeatherVane when `scanf` return `EOF`? when we enter something which is not a number like a char.

Comment: @hanie when there is *no data* to be scanned. When there is some data, but of the wrong type to be scanned, `scanf` returns `0`. [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of items successfully scanned, or `EOF` if there is no data.

Answer (score 2):

As, [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675068/correct-scanf-in-a-while-loop/60675982#comment107349335_60675068), the `==1` is important if `scanf()` returns `EOF` (End Of File or -1) which would be evaluated to `true` and since the value in `number` remains unchanged from the previous iteration the condition of the `while` loop would be evaluated to `true`.

This is not appropriate since we have an error at the scan process then and the condition should be `false` or `0`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, [`scanf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html), will return one of three `int` values.

- `EOF`: a negative value for the end of stream or a read error, (if one wants to differentiate the latter case, see [`ferror(stdin)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ferror.html) or [`!feof(stdin)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/feof.html), and on POSIX-conforming systems, `errno` will be set,)
- `0`: a matching error, and
- `1`: a successfully matched floating-point number that is stored in `number`.

Therefore,

```
while(scanf("%f", &number) && number > 0)
while(scanf("%f", &number) == 1 && number > 0)
```

1. The first `scanf("%f", &number) [!= 0] && ...` will return false on `[0]`, true on `[EOF, 1]`. On `1`, in the case of one variable, it will work as expected, but on `EOF`, it proceeds along the short-circuit to read from uninitialised memory; in the next call to `scanf`, it will probably hang waiting for input from `stdin` that's (most likely) been closed.
2. The second `scanf("%f", &number) == 1 && ...` will return false on `[EOF, 0]`, true on `[1]`. This explicitly confirms that the variable has been written before continuing to the next statement. This is more robust and will take care of matching and read errors together, and works properly proceeding to the second predicate to check if it's in the domain.

However, it doesn't record why the loop stopped, and subsequent reads may have problems. To get that information, one could assign a variable to the return value of `scanf`.