# Default value for empty entry with scanf() in C

Tags: c, scanf

I was looking at the below C code from a study site and wanted to confirm if the default value for an empty entry with scanf("%d", number ) is -1? . That is if 'number' is an 'empty entry' does it automatically get interpreted as -1?

How does the below code not run the first if statement (increment counter) in the 'do" section if the empty entry is not understood as a -1?

```
int main(void)
{
    int number;
    int max = -100000;
    int counter = 0;

    do {
        scanf("%d",&number);
        if(number != -1)
            counter++;
            if(number > max)
                max = number;
    }
    while (number != -1);
        if(counter)
          printf("The largest number is %d \n",max);
        else
            printf("Hey, you haven't entered any number!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty entry"?

Comment: If scanf returns 1, then `number` is assigned a value depedning on what was read from stdin.  If `scanf` does not return 1, then `number` remains uninitialized and accessing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: do while loop is similar to while loop with the only difference that it checks for the condition after executing the statements

Comment: See a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675068/what-is-the-use-of-scanf-1/60676457#60676457), you must check the return value.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "default value" for `scanf`. If `scanf` fails,  no assignment will be made to the pointed to object.

So the idea of the code is that the loop shall continue until the the user inputs a `-1`.

The code lacks a check of the return value from `scanf`, i.e. instead of just

```
scanf("%d",&number);
```

the code should be like

```
if (scanf("%d",&number) != 1)
{
     // Invalid input
     // Add error handling or just exit
     exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can depend on scanf leaving the pointed to objects alone in the case of an error. If you had n conversions to make in the scanf format string, and the conversion failed somehow on the mth object, scanf may have already performed some conversions, right?

Comment: [scanf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fscanf.html) returns 1, `EOF`, or 0. If one needs to differentate matching error from physical error, assign the return of `scanf` to a variable.

Comment: The above code I provided already works as expected, such that if you do not enter anything to the console and hit enter, it prints ""Hey, you haven't entered any number!". But my question is: How does it manage to work correctly? given that if "empty" is not equal to -1, so counter should increment in the "do" block. and if counter is not zero, then the "while" block should print " "The largest number is  Max " and not "Hey, you haven't entered any number!"

Comment: @blessedk If you just press "enter" nothing happens in your code. `scanf` just "eats" the newlines and ignore them.

Comment: OK now I think I get what you mean. That seems like a bit of an 'amateur" code :)(because I am new to C I couldn't say that, but if I were doing this in a language I am conversant with, I wont rely on the fact that the code will not respond to something), so it appears the "if" block does not even run at all when I enter nothing and hit enter. So because the "if" statement does not run at all in that case, the 'counter' variable will not increment. I thought that the "if" would run and was wondering how the code will handle the if (number != -1) with a "number" variable that does not exist

Comment: So  a key learning point for me in C.  A code section simply wont run if there is an argument/variable  that points to a location in memory without a value, and it wont necessarily throw any errors to notify me :)

Comment: @blessedk Well... more or less... C allows you to "shoot yourself in the foot" That's a price you pay form performance. The code runs... but what happens in unknow... in general called: Undefined Behavior.