# getting an input of chars until EOF in c

Tags: c, scanf, eof

I want to to scan chars until EOF and store them in a char array.

I wrote:

```
char current;
int i = 0;
while (scanf(" %c", &current) != EOF)
{
arr[i] = current;
i++;
}
//then do some calculations with arr
```

when I tested the code with this implementation it worked for 4 input tests that I was given, but failed the automated check my teaching assistants ran.
I was wondering if it is related to EOF.
should I try while (scanf(" %c", &current) != 1) instead?

- Please note that i can only use scanf as per my intro to cs class rules.
- Going out of bound of arr is not an issue here.

Edit: the assignment was to get a sequence of chars until EOF and print
the follwing :
*how many digits total
*longest digit subqequence
*for each digit 0-9 to print how many times that digit occured divided by num of total digits
*print n x n matrix , each box containing how many times digit i appeared before digit j

```
Example input - 012a"we228228
My output :
Number of digits: 9
Longest digit subsequence: 6
Frequencies: 0.11 0.11 0.56 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.22 0.00
Sequential:
  0 1 2 8 
0 0 1 5 2 
1 0 0 5 2 
2 0 0 10 8 
8 0 0 2 1
```

The thing is this output matches the expected one , but i failed the auto test my teacher ran (with an automated program) and im not sure why.
Thought it might have something to do with EOF implemented wrong

Comment: You should post [mcve]. You might have some unrelated error elsewhere.

Comment: What test data did you use? What test data is used in the automated test?

Comment: `scanf` does not return the character that was read. It returns the number of items scanned.

Comment: @JeffHolt the program does not rely on `scanf` returning the input value but on returning `EOF` if no more data is entered.

Comment: @Gerhardh The person writing the code thinks `scanf` is supposed to return the EOF character. Correcting that misunderstanding is key.

Comment: @JeffHolt It is not a misunderstanding... It is returning EOF on EOF.

Comment: @JeffHolt I am not sure about EOF *character* but it is supposed to return `EOF` value if the end of the file is reached: *The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.*

Comment: I never test `scanf` for `EOF` because the return value `0` isn't caught. I would do `while (scanf(" %c", &current) == 1)`. Test the for the specfic number of conversions required.

Comment: Ah right, nevermind... too little coffee, as always.

Comment: [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can return `0`, so you might change it to `> 0` or `== 1`.

Comment: Although, I'm not sure when `%c` would fail except on EOF.

Comment: An interesting question, will `scanf(" %c", &c)` return EOF right away if given spaces-only input? I mean will it consume the whitespaces if not converting `%c` ?

Comment: Looks like it will https://ideone.com/svgVPa (unless ideone is somehow screwing it up). So your code seem to be perfectly valid for what it is trying to do. You need to post [mcve], input, expected and actual outputs.

Comment: But! If you really want to read characters one by one, you really better use `fgetc` or similar, and handle the whitespaces the way *you* want.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the `scanf` filter completes when the first non whitespace character is entered, because the filter removes *all* whitespace, and that can't be known until non-whitespace is entered. One reason why the trailing whitespace in a format string is undesirabkle. You can see this at work with `%s` format, which won't return until a non-empty line is entered.

Comment: Related [what is the return of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60675068/2472827). _Viz_, the return is one of three things.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> ```c
> int scanf( const char          *format, ... );
> int scanf( const char *restrict format, ... );
> ...
> ```
>
> *...*
>
> ##### Return value
>
> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or **EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.**

So, what you are asking for is getting an input of chars until an *input failure* occurs before the first receiving argument is assigned.

What you might be asking for is probably getting an input of chars until a *matching failure* occurs before the first receiving argument is assigned. In this case, you may want to do:

```c
char current;
int ret;
while ((ret = scanf(" %c", &current)) != EOF || ret != 0) {
    arr[i] = current;
    i++;
}
```

> *...* but failed the automated check my teaching assistants ran.

Can you edit your question and provide the automated check?

Comment: I don't think it is providing an answer to the question. What kind of "matching failure" can occur for a `%c` specifier?

Comment: The simpler `while (scanf(" %c", &current) == 1)` will do, and the same idea can be used with any `scanf` format string. Checking the *specific number* of conversions is usually essential.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Personally, I've never come across any situation in which `scanf` failed matching a character. But the OP's code is expecting a failure, which is wrong.

Comment: It will fail if the input is redirected from file - at EOF.

Comment: i think my post lacked information and i edited it now sorry for that . i added sample input and my output